# Drupal 7: add html block as field in content type insert/edit form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, custom-fields

I created my content type with fields of different kinds (text, date, entity relation...).
I would like to add an html block (my purpose is to add a link) between two fields. It should not be editable by the user filling the form and the link should be clickable.

I searched for modules (like "html block field") but I still haven't a solution.

Could you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please used markup field module.

https://www.drupal.org/project/markup

Here you can show simple text or html text.